# Error to install psycopg2 install in aws(ubuntu) , how to solve?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, psycopg2

```
Collecting psycopg2 Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB) 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /home/ubuntu/egrdb/env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv0 = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gn70jweq/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gn70jweq/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gn70jweq/psycopg2/ Complete output (7 lines): running egg_info creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8/psycopg2.egg-info writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4tr67ll8/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt' Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you install `postgresql-server-dev-X.Y ` where `X.Y` is your postgres version or `libpq-dev` for the client side version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the source version psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz then you will need to do as @Chris says. The simpler way though is to do:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Then you get a pre-compiled version and you don't need the -dev packages.